# How to disable print button on laptop keyboard?

Tags: windows-7

I have an HP Pavilion dv6 laptop. The keyboard has a print button on the side which seems to trigger the ctrl+p (print) keyboard shortcut. Is there a way to disable this button?

Comment: Try downloading [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) and see whether the program is able to detect it. The same program could be then used to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [HP support forum post](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/HP-Pavilion-dv6-Keyboard-software/td-p/608063), there appear to be a couple options for you to try.

1. You can download and install [QuickPlay
   Remapper](http://www.quickplay.hostzi.com/)
2. Edit the registry

> Your appkeys can be found in the Windows  registry
>
> **HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Appkey**
>
> There will be numbered Keys (7, 15, 18)  in the appkey Key, these can
>   be modified to meet your needs

---

***WARNING: Editing the registry incorrectly can cause Windows not to functions properly. If you choose to edit the registry, make a backup first.***